# Check string for certain characters

Tags: java, string, validation

I'm receiving 2 Strings as inputs. The 1st is the name and the 2nd is the symbol. The symbol has to be exactly 2 chars.  For the symbol to be valid, its letters has to appear in the name in order.
e.g 
Name: "Notepad" and 
Symbol: 'Nt' or 'Te' would be valid but 'Et' or 'Da' is invalid.

Comment: so the symbol does not have to be 2 characters in the right order following immediately? or why is Nt valid? if nt would be invalid and only thing like No, ot, te and so on are valid, you can use the string.contains() method

Comment: @XtremeBaumer 'Nt' is valid because 'N' comes before 'T', basically as long as the second letter in the symbol doesn't come before the first.

Answer (score 2):

You can build your own regex to check if the symbole is correct or not, for example :

```
String str = "Notepad";
String symbole = "tN";
String regex = "(?i).*";
for(int i = 0; i<symbole.length(); i++){
    regex+=symbole.charAt(i)+".*";
}
System.out.println(str.matches(regex));
```

For example for the Outputs:

```
Symbole          Regex           Result

tN              (?i).*t.*N.*     false
Nt              (?i).*N.*t.*     true
Nd              (?i).*N.*d.*     true
NeD             (?i).*N.*e.*D.*  true
```

`(?i)` for case-insensitive?

## Ideone demo

Answer (score 0):

The logic is -

- find "the first character of the symbol" in the string
- if found, then, find "the second character of the system" in the string starting right after the index of first's

-

```
public boolean isValid(String str1, String str2){
    String t1, t2;
    t1 = str1.toLowerCase();
    t2 = str2.toLowerCase();

    if( t1.indexOf( t2.charAt(0) ) > -1 )
    if( t1.indexOf( t2.charAt(1), t1.indexOf(t2.charAt(0))) > -1 )
        return true;

    return false;
}
```